# Passing a List into a method, modify the list within the method without affecting 'original'

Tags: c#, .net, list

Sorry if the subject seems vague, I tried summing it up as best I can without knowing the exact terminology of what I'm trying to achieve.

Essentially I have a list and then I call a method

```
public List<int> myList;

void Start () {
    myList = new List<int>();
    myList.Add (1);
    myList.Add (2);

    doSomething(myList);

    foreach (int i in myList){
        print (i);
    }
}
```

In my method I'd like to do this (for example)

```
public void doSomething (List<int> myPassedList) 
{

    int A = 5;
    myPassList.Add (A);
    //... And then some other cool code with this modified list
}
```

However, I dont want the original list changed, I want it exactly as it was. Essentially when I pass the list into the method I'd like a duplicate of the list, which is then made new each time the method is called.

I want to see the console print '1' then '2'

but it will print '1', '2' and '5'

Hopefully this all makes sense! Thanks very much in advance for any help

Jim

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`List` is a reference type so when you pass `myPassedList` as an argument to `doSomething` you are modifying the original list.

You have two options, either call [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) or create a new list, as an example:

```
public void doSomething (List<int> myPassedList) 
{
    List<int> newList = myPassedList.ToList();
    int A = 5;
    newList.Add(A);
    //... And then some other cool code with this modified list
}
```

The original list `myList` will then only return 1 and 2.

Comment: It's worth noting that for reference types this new list will contain the objects from the original list, so any modifications will be done to both lists' object

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know why passing a variable into a method won't change the original but lists will? Is it because lists are references to something?

Comment: @Jim - no problem.  Look up reference types and value types.  Lists are reference types and you can have multiple variables pointing to the same object (Which is what happened in your case), value types will make another copy of that variable and allow you to modify it without affecting the original.

Answer (score 11):

If you write a method that works with a list but will not modify that list, then you should **document this** by code with

```
public void doSomething ( IEnumerable<int> myPassedValues ) 
{
    List<int> newList = myPassedValues.ToList();
    int A = 5;
    newList.Add(A);
    //... And then some other cool code with this modified list
}
```

Now you and all others will know, just **by reading the declaration** that the passed list will not be modified in this method.

Comment: Hi Rufo, thanks very much for your reply. Could explain why IEnumerable would help me know that the list will not be modified?

Comment: Because you only guarantee that you will receive an `IEnumerable<int>` and that cannot be modified. You should use only the minimum type you need to do your work. It is safer and you can handle anything that inherits from/supports that type/interface.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your doSomething() method, create a duplicate list by:

```
var newList = new List<int>(myPassedList);
int A = 5;
newList.Add (A);
```

myPassedList will not be affected

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy all the items to a new list.

```
 public void doSomething (List<int> myPassedList) 
 {
     List<int> list = myPassedList.GetRange(0, myPassedList.Count);
 }
```

Answer (score -6):

Simply you can clone the original list in the function

```
    public void doSomething (List<int> myPassedList) 
 {
     List<int> clonedList = myPassedList;

// doing something here with clonedList
     }
```

Comment: This is still a pointer to the original list, as I pointed out in the other answer